# Detect simple geometric shapes using PILLOW(PIL)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have this project were I need Python to detect simple geometric shapes inside an image. Only using Pillow, for example:

[image]

After searching the internet, I still don't know how to achieve this. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: this is not a trivial question I would start with reading this perhaps http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/shape_checker/  (just read it to understand the concepts of shape detection) ... then you need to get the pill data as a 2d array of somesort ... and write the BlobFinder method or whatever... once you find a glob you can then try and detect what it is

Comment: Thanks Joran much appreciated. I will start by reading the article.

Answer (score 13):

Get edges first.

```
Magnitude = sqrt(dx2+dy2)
```

Threshold and convert to `0,1` magnitude image.  Follow lines and look for corners, following perimeters of shapes.

Or write more complex corner detection algorithms as found in `OpenCV`.

Shape is based in number of corners found.  (Looks like `GTKbai`!)

Comment: You're quite right, a component of KBA RPM test I is pulling out these 'sub-images'. Thanks for this I will try it out.